# Error Loading Preview on Firebase Storage when click on the image

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

We are making app for school project.. and we use firebase as our database.. when I try to directly upload the image files on firebase storage, I cant view it, theres this message "Error loading preview".. while my other team member can view it on his device.. same thing happen when uploading and retrieving images to our app.. I cant seem to upload and view image(using Piccasso and Glide) on my device.. but my other group member works fine..

Im using my phone to run our app. Storing and retreiving other data works fine except for images.
please help